# How to run tomcat before starting test

Tags: java, continuous-integration, tomcat7, pom.xml

after two days of search, I still cannot run tomcat before test, can anyone tell what i am not doing right ? here is my pom

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>integration-test</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>verify</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<configuration>
    <server>tomcat-development-server</server>
    <port>8081</port>
    <path>/test</path>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>start-tomcat</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>stop-tomcat</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>shutdown</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

when I use mvn verify my tests start, but the server not, I don't know what i'm missing !

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by adding this code in pre-integration-test phase

```
<configuration>
        <fork>true</fork>
</configuration>
```